# If $\iota(x,y,u,v):=(x+iy,u+iv)$, then $\iota(x,y,(x,y)A^T)$ is complex subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\iota\colon \mathbb{R}^4\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^2$ be the function defined by $\iota(x,y,u,v):=(x+iy,u+iv)$. Let $A\in \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb R)$ be an invertible $2\times 2$-matrix with real coefficients. I want to do two things:

> 1. Prove that $V=\{(x,y,(x,y)A^T)\in \mathbb R^4\mid x,y\in \mathbb R\}$ is a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$,

and

> 2. Characterise all matrices $A\in \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\iota(V)\subseteq \mathbb C^2$ is a complex one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$,

where $A^T$ is the transpose matrix of $A$ and $(x,y)A^T$ denotes matrix multiplication. 
I have already tried a few things but somehow I don’t seem to get the right approach. Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks for your help and stay healthy!

Comment: For 1. consider map $f(\vec v) = (\vec v, \vec vA^T)$ which has a trivial kernel and which image is your subspace.

Comment: Could you explain more explicitly? I don’t really get it...

Comment: Define $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^4$ as $f(x,y) = (x,y, (x,y)A^T)$. This map is linear, has trivial kernel (it's injective) and its image is exactly $V$. Hence $V\simeq \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I get the idea for point 1! What can I do for the second part?

Comment: I wish I knew a slick way od solving this! ;) You can try to solve it by hand – explicitly write what $\iota(V)$ is (this is easy) and then see what constraints on $A$ are implied by assumption that any vector in $\iota(V)$ multiplied by a complex number lands in $\iota(V)$. However this approach is so long that I haven't finished it.

Comment: Thanks for your effort :) I also tried doing it by hand but I couldn’t find a way out either. Do you mind upvoting my question to increase the chances of someone seeing it? I really need the second point too in order to continue my research.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106274/discussion-between-pawel-czyz-and-mathismath).